# iOS obj-c move from UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have successfully created a "tutorial" pages that will show up at the first time user open the app. And i am facing the problem on how to move to another "branch" of view controllers in my storyboard.

So basically I have two main flows in my storyboard:

```
1. Page View Controllers 
2. Main app view controllers
```

As you can see from screenshot below

[image: Screen Shot]

So, the question is, how to move to my main app flow after the user clicked on the skip button from my UIPageViewController?

In my tutorial page view controller, i have this code to set the page view controllers

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.arrPageTitles = @[@"A",@"B",@"C"];
self.arrPageImages =@[@"1.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"3.jpg"];

// Create page view controller
self.PageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pageViewController"];
self.PageViewController.dataSource = self;

TutorialPageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self.PageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

// Change the size of page view controller
self.PageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

[self addChildViewController:self.PageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.PageViewController.view];
[self.PageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Or is there any better approach to achieve this? Is my design wrong?

I have searching for any clue but can't find any. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd recommend you to use different storyboards for Tutorial flow and for main app screens. It's very hard to store everything in single storyboard: you will get some mess when project will have at least 20-30 view controllers.

And you can replace root view controller at any time using this code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "<storyboard_name>", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "<vc_name>")
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
```